# Are there Perl GUI builders, especially for WxPerl?

Tags: perl, user-interface, wxperl

Are there good GUI builder for Perl GUI libraries, especially for WxPerl?

Comment: Are you wanting to build a "GUI library" or simply build a GUI?

Comment: simply build a GUI (i want a gui builder for perl like Jigloo for java)

Answer (score 13):

For Wx:

- [WxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/)
- Any Wx tool that generates XRC files.

For Tk:

- [Zooz](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ZooZ.pl)
- [SpeTcl](http://spectcl.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 12):

[wxDesigner](http://www.wxdesigner-software.de/) is the only one I know. I have never used it though.

Answer (score 7):

It's still fairly new, but the Padre editor has an in-development [Padre::Plugin::FormBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Padre%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aFormBuilder) plugin that takes a wxFormBuilder project file and generates pure-Perl dialog classes.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [wxformbuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/). You can design your GUI there and generate an XRC file which wxPerl can then be configured to load.

Answer (score 4):

There is [The GUI Loft](http://www.darserman.com/Perl/Loft/) for [Win32::GUI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GUI/), but of course it's not portable off of Win32.

Comment: It seems that "The GUI Loft" doesn't support Unicode (or UTF-8). A big drawback.

Answer (score 4):

Of the GUI editors that I have tried briefly, [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/index.php) seems the most natural to use, but it still doesn't seem to have the "drag and drop" functionality that I grew to love when working with Java in Eclipse or Netbeans. Don't get me wrong, I love Perl, but would still really like to see a nice WYSIWYG GUI editor.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend simply using web-based interfaces for everything. If you went with this approach, you could even run a local (i.e. on a Desktop) web server for "standalone" applications.

In like manner, ActiveState [decided to focus on Web-based development instead of continuing work on their GUI editor](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/komodo-announce/3355346)

Comment: In many cases this approach will work.  As rich AJAX widget sets become available, this works even better.  However, sometimes you really need a normal, GUI app. The downvoters are missing the point that this is a valid approach to building app interfaces, and has been for years.

Comment: http://www.perl.com/lpt/a/884 - shows a flash based GUI with a perl backend.  Communication via HTTP.  This http://www.chrisdolan.net/yapcna2006/shrinkwrap.html shows a method using PAR and SOAP to build apps, with the GUI written in whatever toolset makes sense to the developer.